# VS2012 fails to resolve printf,

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I've just reinstalled VS2012, when trying to compile a simple "hello world" it failed to find the most basic functions, I've tried going through linking options or compiler options for c++ looking for nostd or some similar option from GCC but failed to do so

can anyone hint me what am I missing ? this is obviously a configuration problem I can't seem to resolve

just to clear thing, when I use cl from the command line "cl test.cpp -o test.exe" it works, this means it is some configuration problem I'm missing

can anyone help out ?

```
1>------ Build started: Project: test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 8/24/2013 1:52:58 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\test.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  test.cpp
1>LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/map(filename)'; ignored
1>test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__printf referenced in function _main
1>test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __RTC_CheckEsp referenced in function _main
1>test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_InitBase
1>test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_Shutdown
1>LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup
1>C:\_projects\code\c\test\Debug\test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.47
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

here's the same error after adding a subsystem and entrypoint

```
1>------ Build started: Project: test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 8/24/2013 2:37:29 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\test.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/map(filename)'; ignored
1>LINK : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/INCREMENTAL' due to '/RELEASE' specification
1>main.obj : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/OPT:LBR' specification
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__printf referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __RTC_CheckEsp referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_InitBase
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_Shutdown
1>C:\_projects\code\C\test\Debug\test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.17
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

just to note, this is a console project

linker options:

```
/OUT:"C:\_projects\code\C\test\Debug\test.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\_projects\code\C\test\Debug\test.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /ENTRY:"_tmain" /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"C:\_projects\code\C\test\Debug\test.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Debug\test.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1
```

c/c++ options:

```
/Yu"stdafx.h" /MP /GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm /Od /sdl /Fd"Debug\vc110.pdb" /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /fp:except- /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /GR- /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"Debug\" /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\test.pch"
```

Comment: What kind of project type are you creating doesn't look like a console app...?

Comment: it is a console one :/

Answer (score 0):

It has been asked several times here all around, but the problem is that you have not selected "Console" application type, but rather the win32 gui. You need to be careful about the proper linker selection, too.

Comment: File -> New -> Project -> Win32 Console Application -> name your app -> click next -> click application settings? It works for me...

Comment: @dotdot: have you tried this, too? GoTo Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Advanced

Put "main" to the "Entry Point" field. Or this one: Go to "Linker settings -> System". Change the field "Subsystem" from "Windows" to "Console". Done. Also, have you made a clean build after this, i.e. removing all the previous object files, etc?

Comment: hi, I just tried it, it didn't help. why would it help ? for some unknown reason VS2012 can't seem to find those symbols while linking, this is how I understand it anywho

Comment: Hi, I tried both "Console" and "Windows" (there was no subsystem defined there in the original option), none, same error

Comment: I am not surprised it still does not work if you had not set the linker subsystem to console, too.

Comment: What windows is this? What architecture, etc? Have you tried 2010? Is this an example project?

Comment: what should i do then? it's quite frustrating not being able to compile anything

Comment: The file is properly added to the project, and so forth? Can you try to build it from command line with cl.exe just for a quick try? Also, it is actually not a printf problem then, so you can update the title?

Comment: it works, i used the "x86 command line" and use cl test.cpp -o test.exe and got it working. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please create a brand new project from scratch. It is clearly some fishy VS setup. I understand you are frustrated, and I am also getting that it cannot work. ;)

Comment: ok, Win32 -> Win32 Console Project right? I'm removing the precompield header and the SDL checks also

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36157/discussion-between-dotdot-and-laszlo-papp)

Comment: So, the outcome of the chat, try vm or/and vs2010 for a quick test. This looks a serious mess up. :)